# How to downgrade bootstrap from version 4 to 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am working  on a project that is using bootstrap 4. How do I downgrade the version being used on the project from 4 to 3 while maintaining the functionality of the website.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way. To do that, you have to check on all html pages and javascript files.